# Kusto query to look for specific characters only in list

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

I am new to Kusto and I am trying to create a binary flag(in column "RemoteURL") based on "ProcessAccount Values". If process account contains c, r, n or any combination of the 3, "RemoteUrl" should be True. Otherwise it should be false(note that if Process account has any other entries in addition to c,r,n then RemoteUrl should be false)

What I have so far is below(this only checks if c, r, n are present, but it doesn't exclude cases when other accounts are present in addition to c,r,n :

```
let type = dynamic(["c", "r", "n"]);
DeviceNetworkEvents
| where RemoteUrl in~ (type)
| project TimeGenerated, DeviceName, ProcessAccount, RemoteUrl
```

**Input table is:**

| TimeGenerated | DeviceName | ProcessAccount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | device1 | ["a","c","I","n"] |
| 2023-01-01 | device2 | ["c","n","r"] |
| 2023-01-01 | device3 | ["n"] |
| 2023-01-01 | device4 | ["r","n"] |
| 2023-01-01 | device5 | ["s","c","n","r"] |

**Expected Output table is:**

| TimeGenerated | DeviceName | ProcessAccount | RemoteUrl |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 | device1 | ["a","c","I","n"] | FALSE |
| 2023-01-01 | device2 | ["c","n","r"] | TRUE |
| 2023-01-01 | device3 | ["n"] | TRUE |
| 2023-01-01 | device4 | ["r","n"] | TRUE |
| 2023-01-01 | device5 | ["s","c","n","r"] | FALSE |

Answer (score 0):

```
let DeviceNetworkEvents = datatable(TimeGenerated:datetime, DeviceName:string, ProcessAccount:dynamic)
[
    datetime(2023-01-01), "device1" ,dynamic(["a","c","I","n"])
   ,datetime(2023-01-01), "device2" ,dynamic(["c","n","r"])
   ,datetime(2023-01-01), "device3" ,dynamic(["n"])
   ,datetime(2023-01-01), "device4" ,dynamic(["r","n"])
   ,datetime(2023-01-01), "device5" ,dynamic(["s","c","n","r"])
   ,datetime(2023-01-01), "device6" ,dynamic([])
   ,datetime(2023-01-01), "device7" ,dynamic(null)
];
let type = dynamic(["c", "r", "n"]);
DeviceNetworkEvents
| project TimeGenerated
         ,DeviceName
         ,ProcessAccount
         ,RemoteUrl =       array_length(set_difference(ProcessAccount, type)) == 0 
                        and array_length(ProcessAccount) > 0
```

| TimeGenerated | DeviceName | ProcessAccount | RemoteUrl |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01T00:00:00Z | device1 | ["a","c","I","n"] | false |
| 2023-01-01T00:00:00Z | device2 | ["c","n","r"] | true |
| 2023-01-01T00:00:00Z | device3 | ["n"] | true |
| 2023-01-01T00:00:00Z | device4 | ["r","n"] | true |
| 2023-01-01T00:00:00Z | device5 | ["s","c","n","r"] | false |
| 2023-01-01T00:00:00Z | device6 | [] | false |
| 2023-01-01T00:00:00Z | device7 |  | false |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA42S30vDMBDH3/NXHHlqIELX%20QM6KgiK%20CIi%20jTGiOltVtN0JLdJwT/etG6sGSK95F4u%20XxzlzuDBLe4qzQ%20In017vNuh5Y8FFAqCuvNYPJS1XiPFp0iLPMQRwoReeBUjbknV9m1hCfXaPT%20RutmaykvW6vqSgs2ZxDsgCZZmk3P0knYQgIve50JB7m/n8y54pLr4A/BLV%20Ijpf/8lnE656T3I1ipxE77r3ziHGj87yIOL%20vc3yul0N%20DHA1AOzWGMEWM2ZC36ndYNfo4adBVwn0pczYH4PBvmHjmg/UBNFY9P3tTR7HYhCMB2Nw8Ix1Q/jqTMjk15Rzql0atGt6TzzSsqxWK3RoNSaxjOxLEAKKAlI4ip6YsmUsGqsIuIb0BwfVxysIAwAA)